# Bulk import .csv files into mysql workbench database (something other than through php)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

> > > Don't mark my question as duplicate, because none of the answers that are already on the forum solved my problem, as the answers are very old<<<

I have a folder with several .csv files and I would like to import all the files in this folder en masse into mysql, without having to do it one by one.

Is there any code that does this?

I currently use the code below, but this way I can only import 1 at a time, but I will need to import more than 300 files.

```
START transaction;
load data local infile 'C:/Users/novar/Desktop/Banco de Dados/teste.csv' into table teste_loja
CHARACTER SET latin1
fields terminated by ';'
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
lines terminated by '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: better write a short python program or use one that you find